# Github, forked repositories ahead of master: active users

Tags: git, github, commit, git-fork

There is a certain repository that has been forked by many tens of users. However most of them are inactive. The ones that are still active will probably have n commits ahead of master. However when I click on fork I can see all the users that forked but I cannot select the ones that are active.

Is there a way to see who's active or who has commits ahead of master?

Comment: For more ideas see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54868988/278842

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can click on the **Insights** tab (next to **Issues** and **Pull requests**) and you will see a sidebar on the left.

Then click on **Network**. You will see the most active forks there.

For example:
https://github.com/cyverse/clank/network