# How to find the github fork of a project with the most recent commit?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

Is there a way (other than try them all..) to find which fork for an (abandoned) GitHub project has the most recent commit? The default list of forks returned by GitHub is by fork date I believe...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54868988/how-to-determine-which-forks-on-github-are-ahead

Comment: Github seem to have a tool. For example https://useful-forks.github.io/?repo=mrdoob%2Fthree.js shows a table of forks for `mrdoob/three.js` and the date shown is the _"Date of the most recent push in ANY branch of the repository"_.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Saying "Github has a tool..." implies that that tool is in some way official, which it doesn't seem to be. The `.github.io" domain is just the domain for user's content hosted on [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/). The tool just [automates the process of looking through all the forks in turn](https://github.com/useful-forks/useful-forks.github.io#how-it-works).

Comment: @IMSoP I completely forgot I had "refined github" extension installed.

Comment: @0stone0: thanks, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68335748/1586860) on the thread you posted looked the simplest way... thanks